# How to remove doc strings when using Cython distutils?

Tags: python, cython

I can remove the docstrings if I invoke cython manually, eg:

```
cython -D mmod.py
```

but when I try to use the setup utility, I am unable to pass that -D parameter along.

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("mmod", ["mmod.py"])]

setup(
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

This produces a library that has all doc strings available, compared to when running with -D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cython compiling option are stored in the module `Cython.Compiler.Options`. So what you are looking for is

```
import Cython.Compiler.Options
Cython.Compiler.Options.docstrings = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Any idea how to get rid of other strings in .so files? I see in my cythonized files there are still method names etc.

Comment: yoel: you cannot remove all those strings since Python need them to call the functions/methods.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know of a way of obscurifying them? meaning, changing their names randomly?

Comment: yoel: I would do it at the source level, but I don't think this would add much security / obfuscation to our code. If you really want obfuscated code, use C / assembly, certainly not Python.