# Do not include Cython metadata in generated C files

Tags: cython

When generating C files from Cython code, the `cython` compiler adds metadata about the used version and the absolute file paths of the original Cython files. This looks something like this:

```
/* BEGIN: Cython Metadata
{
    "distutils": {
        "depends": [
            "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/package/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h",
            "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/package/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h"
        ],
        "extra_compile_args": [
            "-O3"
        ],
        "include_dirs": [
            "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/package/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include"
        ]
    }
}
END: Cython Metadata */

# code removed for (relative) brevity

/* "../../.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython-0.23.4-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd":728
* ctypedef npy_int16      int16_t
* ctypedef npy_int32      int32_t
* ctypedef npy_int64      int64_t             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
* #ctypedef npy_int96      int96_t
* #ctypedef npy_int128     int128_t
*/
typedef npy_int64 __pyx_t_5numpy_int64_t;
```

As I share a git repository with several developers and we commit the generated C files, this creates a lot of useless chatter in the git logs. Even minor changes in the Cython code create changes in the whole corresponding C file.

Is there a way to disable the writing of this metadata? I found a way to remove docstrings ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569577/how-to-remove-doc-strings-when-using-cython-distutils)) by setting a compiler option, but this did not solve my issue. I have looked through the other compiler directives and options, but found nothing that did the trick.

Comment: I don't think it's officially supported, but I wonder if you examined the objects that `cythonize` returns in setup.py then you might be able to remove it. (This is a guess at where I'd start looking - it may well not work).

Comment: "Even minor changes in the Cython code create changes in the whole corresponding C file." - I think this is unavoidable with any kind of generated file. Although I agree that removing the metadata would help a bit.